# How to install Java extension on VS Code 32 bit windows 7

Tags: java, java-8

I was trying to install the VS Code Java extension on Windows 7 (32-bit). It says that the extension crashed 5 times.
I have VS Code 32-bit Windows 7
and
JDK 8 Windows 7 (32-bit).

I tried again, it installed something that adds snippets to Java files but didn't install the full extension.

I asked ChatGPT about it, but it just said to do the things that I already tried.

I tried:

1. Use a different IDE, but because my Windows is 32-bit, there were not many.
2. Do something with the configure setting, but I'm a beginner so I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Most IDEs are written in Java and should theoretically run on either 64 or 32. Ironically you've chosen one that isn't.

Comment: chatGPT is banned in Stackoverlow.

Comment: @aled you wrote (in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77786193/how-to-install-java-extension-on-vs-code-32-bit-windows-7#comment137131582_77786193)): _chatGPT is banned in Stackoverlow._ I think that means copy-pasting text that was generated by ChatGPT. I don't think that is the case with this question. I believe that the OP is saying that he simply tried to get help from ChatGPT.

Comment: In a related issue, you know there's no future in Windows 7 x86 don't you? It will continue to give you problems.

Comment: @Abra that is not helpful to readers of the question. In any case I interpret all use of generative AI as any use: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned